# I need to refresh a datatable after an ajax action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I need to refresh a datatable after an ajax action, I've tried everything I found and nothing helps me, the datatable manual says to use the table.api().ajax.reload(); but I can't make it wor, also tried to destroy the datatable and render it again and doesn't work, please I need help.

this is my code:

```
var form=document.getElementById("formEditMantenimientoRolDetails");
var formData = new FormData(form);
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ path('editRolMantenimiento') }}',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
        if (returndata.success == true) {
            $.unblockUI();
            $('#editRol').modal('hide');
            Notificacion("success", "Valoración RP", "Los datos se han guardado correctamente.");
            $('#sample_2').load(window.location + ' #sample_2 >  *');
        }
    }
})
```

This line `($('#sample_2').load(window.location + ' #sample_2 >  *');)` works but I lose the sortable table.

**EDIT:**

my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_2">
   <thead>
       <tr class="header">
           <th class="table-checkbox noprint">
               <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_2 .checkboxes" disabled/>
           </th>
           <th width="20%" style="text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(1)">
               Rol aplicación
           </th>
           <th width="20%" style="text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(2)">
               Descripción del rol
           </th>
           <th width="20%" style="text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(3)">
               Nivel de Permiso
           </th>
           <th width="20%" style="text-align:center;" onclick="sortTable(4)">
               Estado
           </th>
           <th width="20%" class="noprint" style="text-align:center;">
               Acciones
           </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tablaIndexRol">
       {% for rol in rol %}
       <tr class="odd gradeX">
           <td class="noprint">
               <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" disabled/>
           </td>
           <td style="text-align:center;">
               {{ rol.rol }}
           </td>
           <td style="text-align:center;">
               {{ rol.descripcion }}
           </td>
           <td style="text-align:center;">
               {{ rol.permiso.nombre }}
           </td>
           <td style="text-align:center;">
               {% if rol.enabled == 1 %}
               Activo
               {% else %}
               Inactivo
               {% endif %}
           </td>
           <td class="noprint" style="text-align:center;">
               <a class="btn btn-sm default" data-toggle="modal" onclick="showMantenimientoRol({{rol.id}})">Ver</a>
               <a class="btn btn-sm blue" data-toggle="modal" onclick="editMantenimientoRolDetails({{rol.id}})">Editar</a>
           </td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: add your datatable init code.

Comment: @Webinion hello, what dou you mean with the datatable init code? do you mean my table code? I added it, is where the datatable is create.

Comment: not this, `datatable()` function, something like this `$('#myTable').DataTable();`

Comment: @Webinion sorry, I dont have any function like this $('#myTable').DataTable(); where should I put it? I new on these datatable. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To reload datatables, I used this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var DataTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        // insert datatable commands here
    });
```

Then, to reload it,

```
DataTable.ajax.reload();
```

Your code shows no .DataTable({}) function, so that is what you need to add.